# Why does the filter data does not show on the table view?

Tags: swift

So I have the following code where I filter horses whether they are vaccinated or not by clicking 2 buttons. When I debug I see that the additional array I have created where filtered data should be stored is getting actually filtered but then the outcome is not shown on the table view but the old data from the not filtered array stays, why is that and how can I fix it ?

Here is my code:

```
    var horses = [Horse] ()
    var filteredData = [Horse]()

    @IBAction func btnNotVaccined(_ sender: Any) {
            self.filteredData = horses.filter { !$0.vaccinated } // or !$0.vaccinated for the second option
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print(horses.count)
            print(filteredData.count)
            print("Not Vaccined")
        }

        @IBAction func btnVaccined(_ sender: Any) {
            filteredData = horses.filter { $0.vaccinated } // or !$0.vaccinated for the second option
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print(horses.count)
            print(filteredData.count)
            print(" Vaccined")
        }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return self.horses.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "horseCell", for: indexPath)
                     // let buttonCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttonCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text =  "Name: \(self.horses[indexPath.row].name) "
                       //Name:  \(self.horses[indexPath.row].name), \(self.horses[indexPath.row].name)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(self.horses[indexPath.row].medicalReports[0].description )
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "horse")

        return cell
                     // tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        let numbers = 0...1

            let medRep = MedicalReport(id: 1,description: "Flu: Vaccinated, Decontamination: Vaccinated",dateOfTreatment: Date())

            var medicalReports = [MedicalReport] ()
            medicalReports.append(medRep)

            for _ in numbers{

                let horse = Horse(id: 1,name: "Angel",race: "White",gender: Gender.MALE ,medicalReports: medicalReports, vaccinated : false)
                let horse2 = Horse(id: 1,name: "Rambo",race: "White",gender: Gender.MALE ,medicalReports: medicalReports, vaccinated : true)

               // print(medRep.description)

                horses.append(horse);
                horses.append(horse2);
               self.tableView.reloadData()




        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
           return 1
       }
```

Comment: You'll need to show the table datasource methods you have implemented.

Comment: I have updated it now.

Comment: You're using the `horses` array in your datasource methods, you need to use `filteredData` instead.

Comment: Well, yes but I want to show all horses when opened first. Then I can filter.

Comment: Then set `filteredData = horses` when it first loads. You could also consider using the table view search controller and associated scope bar for this.

Comment: Hm, yes, now it shows them all when first started but for some reason it does not filter properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these code changes. This is based on your original code. It creates four horses: two called Angel and two called Rambo - is that what you want?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     return self.filteredData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "horseCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text =  "Name: \(self.filteredData[indexPath.row].name) "
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(self.filteredData[indexPath.row].medicalReports[0].description )
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "horse")

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    let numbers = 0...1

    let medRep = MedicalReport(id: 1, description: "Flu: Vaccinated, Decontamination: Vaccinated",dateOfTreatment: Date())

    var medicalReports = [MedicalReport] ()
    medicalReports.append(medRep)

    for _ in numbers {
        let horse = Horse(id: 1, name: "Angel",race: "White",gender: Gender.MALE ,medicalReports: medicalReports, vaccinated : false)
        let horse2 = Horse(id: 1, name: "Rambo",race: "White",gender: Gender.MALE ,medicalReports: medicalReports, vaccinated : true)

        horses.append(horse);
        horses.append(horse2);
     }

     filteredData = horses
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
}
```